# Jenkins 'email-extension plugin' interpreting wrong WORKSPACE value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using email extension plugin with jelly script to send customized emails for my builds. While I try this on the jenkins installation with no slave (and just the master), it works fine and I get emails as expected.

However, when I use this in a Jenkins installation with slave attached to it, the  WORKSPACE value is not interpreted correctly. 
So here is the jelly script snippet that is failing:

```
 <j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/> 
 <j:set var="myworkspace" value="${buildenv.get('WORKSPACE')}"/> 
<x:parse xml="${myworkspace}/jscs.xml" var="myxmldoc"/>
```

Due to this I am getting an error as follows:

```
JellyException: null:139:60: /var/service/jenkins/Users/JenkinsUser/workspace/Web_Build/jscs.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /var/service/jenkins/Users/JenkinsUser/workspace/Web_Build/jscs.xml (No such file or directory)
```

This is quite strange since WORKSPACE variable when evaulated should ideally give me the value:

```
/Users/JenkinsUser/workspace/Web_Build
```

My understanding says that email-extension plugin is note evaluating the jelly script on the slave but on jenkins master.

Any pointers in resolving this would be appreciated. Many thankS!

Comment: You most probably defined the e-mail notification as a Post-build action. I'm not completely sure about that (and I can't try it atm since I don't have access to a Jenkins with a slave atm) but i can imagine that only Build steps are executed on a slave. I'd try the following: Use the [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) (which also works in the other direction) to copy `jscs.xml` to the master.